# Proper Amazon S3 Deployment Process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

I am currently putting together an angular application which I would like to deploy as a static website using Amazon S3.

What is the best way of doing this? If the website is live and I would like to deploy a new version, should I deploy the new version to a new bucket and change the DNS redirect? Or should I push it to a new folder inside the bucket and modify the index file to refer to that folder?

I would appreciate any further advice from anyone that has experience doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this, but best is to test your angular app/site locally and then redeploy it on S3. It will result in little downtime but that should be fine. Other ways like deploy somewhere else and then point it there require resources and do not guarantee success (what if you missed some config at new bucket etc).

Here is a blog for deploying app to S3 -
https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/deploy-your-angularjs-app-to-aws-s3-with-ssl-3635a62533ab

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! If I deploy a new version to the same bucket I should first halt static web hosting before uploading the new files? My reasoning for creating a new bucket and redirecting is so that downtime is minimized, users will not see broken versions of the site while files are uploading, and I can easily switch back to a previous version if necessary.

Comment: In my previous organization we followed both procedures. I would say if your deployment is small and site is modular then take downtime of short duration and deploy at same place. Otherwise follow different procedure but beware of config changes etc because in production anything can mess. And if you liked the answer plz upvote it :)